# How to transform a text JPQL JPA query into a criteria query?

Tags: java, jpa, jpql

Is it possible to transform a JPQL sting like `select x from Clazz x` into a `CriteriaQuery` object where I could check if the query's root is `Clazz` or not (using `CriteriaQuery.getRoots`) or do the same thing differently (not transforming into `CriteriaQuery`)?

The JPA docs are quite simple (e.g. `CriteriaBuilder`'s class comment says "Return an instance of CriteriaBuilder for the creation of CriteriaQuery objects." - 10 or 20 sentences and references more wouldn't hurt). It thus doesn't mention anything about reversing the `CriteriaQuery -> TypedQuery` process.

[jpa - transforming jpql join query to criteria api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16898452/jpa-transforming-jpql-join-query-to-criteria-api) and [How to convert a JPQL with subquery to Criteria API equivalent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10875591/how-to-convert-a-jpql-with-subquery-to-criteria-api-equivalent) cover concrete cases. I'm looking for a generic programmatic solution.

Specifying a type which doesn't match with the argument of `CriteriaBuilder.createQuery(Class)` causes an `IllegalArgumentException`, but that's more of a workaround and doesn't allow a very useful set of methods to investigate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, not possible, or at least no standardised way.

See also [this issue](https://java.net/jira/browse/JPA_SPEC-29) where someone has requested it for a future version of JPA.